# icacls error during installation of postgres 11.5-1 in win 10?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to install postgresql 11.5 version on windows 10 pro.
Also Run As Administrator but same error.

bitrock_installer log

```
Log started 09/16/2019 at 22:39:59
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Executing icacls "C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_30cfb2bb73" /inheritance:r
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 processed file: C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_30cfb2bb73
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Script stderr:


Executing icacls "C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_30cfb2bb73" /T /Q /grant "vijay:(OI)(CI)F"
Script exit code: 5

Script output:
 Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 1 files

Script stderr:
 C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_30cfb2bb73\*: Access is denied.

Error running icacls "C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_30cfb2bb73" /T /Q /grant "vijay:(OI)(CI)F": C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_30cfb2bb73\*: Access is denied.
Cannot delete file C:/Users/vijay/AppData/Local/Temp/postgresql_installer_30cfb2bb73
```

When i checked for installer dir in temp unknown principal has there
[installer extract dir owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veTIi.png)

also change user temp directory & access permissions but still no success ...